# ItextPdf download issue

Tags: java, pdf, itext

When I try to download PDF using my code it shows error as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dVnr.png).

This is the code for `downloadPdfSample()` function:

```
public void downloadPdfSample() {

    Object object = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    if (!(object instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
        return;
    }

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();

    try {
        int countTotalPratical = 0;
        List<SubjectResultDto> subjectResultDtos = sortSubjectOrder(marksLedgerDataModelJsf.getSubjectResultDtos());

        for (SubjectResultDto subjectResultDto : subjectResultDtos) {
            if (subjectResultDto.isHasPractical()) {
                countTotalPratical++;
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(subjectResultDtos, SubjectResultDto.comparatorBySubjectProgramSemesterMapOrder);
        marks = false;
        grade = false;
        marksAndGrade = false;
        showGraceMarks = false;
        int subjectResultSize = 0;
        float length = 0;
        if ("Marks".equals(marksLedgerDataModelJsf.getReportType())) {
            marks = true;
            subjectResultSize = 1 + subjectResultDtos.size() + countTotalPratical;
            length = 410 + (subjectResultDtos.size()) * 80 + countTotalPratical * 65;
        }
        if ("Grade".equals(marksLedgerDataModelJsf.getReportType())) {
            grade = true;
            subjectResultSize = 2 * subjectResultDtos.size() + 2 * countTotalPratical;
            length = 330 + (subjectResultDtos.size()) * 90 + countTotalPratical * 95;
        }//other codes to set length as required
        length = Math.min(length, 1550);

        int breadth = 800;
        Rectangle rectange = new Rectangle(length, breadth);

        Document document = new Document(rectange);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
        document.open();

        //other codes
        document.add(table);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=Marks_Ledger.pdf");
        try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
            document.close();
            out.close();
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (DocumentException | IOException | RuntimeException e) {
        log.error("An error occurred during PDF generation:", e);
    }
}
```

PDF is not downloaded as required. Downloaded file was corrupted, it mainly occurred when downloading large page sized PDFs.

Comment: Consider setting the content type and the content disposition _before_ starting to write response content, in particular before `PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream())`.

Comment: It is still showing same issue.

Comment: It looks like the client does not get the content disposition and content type or ignores them. Could it be that Faces somehow overrides these values  in your setup?